# Scrapy from outside of project - empty settings

Tags: python, scrapy

I'm trying to run spiders from `Django` management command.

It works but it doesn't use `settings` from `scrapy` project.

```
django_project/
    django_project/
    app1/
    scraping/ # This is app but it has scrapy project inside too
        scrapy_spider/
            settings.py
            spiders/
```

When I try to specify `settings` inside the command, it returns:

```
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'scrapy_spider'
```

**COMMAND**

```
import os
from django.core.management.base import BaseCommand
from scrapy.utils.project import get_project_settings

from twisted.internet import reactor, defer
from scrapy.crawler import CrawlerRunner

from scraping.scrapy_spider.spiders.autoscrape_index_spider import AutoScrapeIndexSpider
from scraping.scrapy_spider.spiders.autoscrape_spider import AutoScrapeSpider


class Command(BaseCommand):

    def handle(self, *args, **options):
        os.environ['SCRAPY_SETTINGS_MODULE'] = 'scraping.scrapy_spider.settings'
        runner = CrawlerRunner(settings=get_project_settings())

        @defer.inlineCallbacks
        def crawl():
            yield runner.crawl(AutoScrapeIndexSpider)
            yield runner.crawl(AutoScrapeSpider)
            reactor.stop()

        crawl()
        reactor.run()
```

Do you know how to make it work?

Comment: Maybe it is related to this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40333400/django-add-management-command-without-installing-as-app

Comment: Do you have `__init__.py` in proper places?